# Page not uploading after res.send()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I am building a `node.js` web app and have a delete function that queries a `mongo` database, deletes a `document` and then sends the user to another page.

However, after the function is invoked the new page doesn't reload even though the `document` is deleted and I can manually load that page. Instead the existing page just sits there.

Here is `GET` message I see from the terminal after the function completes:

```
GET /students 200 9ms - 5.64kb
```

The delete function:

```
remove: function(req, res) {
    function(err, result) {
        Models.Student.remove({myid:{$regex:req.params.students_id}},function(err,removed) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            res.send('/students');
        }
    })
},
```

The function to render the new page:

```
index: function(req, res) {
    var viewModel = {
        student: [],
        };
    Models.Student.find({},function(err, student) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            if (student) {
                viewModel.student=student;
                res.render('../views/students.handlebars',viewModel);
                } 
            else {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
    });    
},
```

The Jquery script:

```
$(function(){
$('#btn-delete').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remove = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?');      
    if (remove) {
        var studentid = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({url: '/students/'+studentid, type: 'DELETE'}).done(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $.ajax(
                    {type: 'GET',
                    url:'/students',
                    success: function(){
                        console.log('success');
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            else{
                console.log('Unable to delete');
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

And the routing:

```
app.get('/students',students.index);
```

I really appreciate any help given.

Comment: The console does not have 'success' written in it after the deletion?

Comment: Your code to update page should be at **console.log('success');**

Comment: hmmm... I am a little confused because I thought that either (1) res.send() or (2) $.ajax (({type: 'GET', url:'/students',) is supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the new page to load by adding a `window` command after done():

```
 $.ajax({url: '/students/'+studentid, type: 'DELETE'}).done(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $.ajax(
                    {type: 'GET',
                    url:'/students',
                    success: function(){
                        console.log('success');
                        window.location.href='/students';
                        }
                    } 
                )
             }
            else{
                console.log('Unable to delete');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

After res.send (), call `return next ();` with no parameter to trigger next middleware which will send 200 status along with /students string.  Only then the done () resolver in ajax will be trigger.

Comment: The console returns 'success' so I think the ajax script did run properly.